# AWSセキュリティグループにIPを追加してもEC2に接続できない

Tags: ssh, amazon-ec2

以下の手順でAWSのセキュリティグループを設定しましたがEC2インスタンスに接続できません。

1. セキュリティグループのインバウンド編集画面を開く
2. 接続タイプは「すべてのトラフィック」を選択
3. ソース(送信元IP)は「マイIP」を選択して送信元のIPを登録
4. ping, sshともにインスタンスにつながらず

ちなみに送信元IPをすべて可(0.0.0.0/0)にするとpingもsshも接続できます(おそらく他の種類・ポートのトラフィックも)。

送信元のグローバルIPは毎日のように変更されるので、接続する前にセキュリティグループに送信元IPをそれに合わせて変更しますが接続できません(グローバルIPが固定の別のネットワーク環境のマシンのIPからは接続できます)。

一度接続できたような記憶がありましたが、その一度だけでその後一向に接続できません。

よろしくお願いします。

Comment: すべて可にしてEC2でのログを確認すると間違いなくその送信元IPで接続されていることは確認できますか？

Comment: EC2内で `w -i` コマンドで送信元のipを確認したところ、セキュリティグループで表示されたマイIPと違うアドレスでした。こちらをセキュリティグループに再登録したところ、sshで接続できました。